# Maven Jdepend report contains no data

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin, jdepend

I'm running the jdepend maven plugin on my project and whether I run "mvn site:site" or "mvn jdepend:generate" the report that gets generated says "There are no package used."  There are no errors in the maven output. Other plugins (cobertura, findbugs, etc.) run fine. My pom is configured like this:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdepend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your java code use packages, in other words, does your source code have package com.mes5k.business, com.mes5k.ui, etc... If you don't have packages and more than one package it can't calculate dependencies.

Comment: Yes, it includes several packages.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running "mvn -U -cpu site:site" to update all the maven dependencies?
Maybe this question is better asked in the Maven forum :)